# EOF marker not found - How to fix in PyPDF and PyPDF2?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm attempting to combine a few PDF files into a single PDF file using Python. I've tried both PyPDF and PyPDF2 - on some files, they both throw this same error:

> PdfReadError: EOF marker not found

Here's my code (page_files) is a list of PDF file paths to combine:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

writer = PdfWriter()
for path in ["example1.pdf", "example2.pdf"]:
    reader = PdfReader(path)            
    for page in reader.pages:
        writer.add_page(page)            

with open("out.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

I've read a few StackOverflow threads on the topic, but none contain a solution that works. If you've successfully combined PDF files using Python, I'd love to hear how.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace telling which line of code is causing the `PdfReadError` to be raised? Also, are you sure the PDF files you're trying to combine are properly formatted? Can Adobe/Acrobat Reader read them OK?

Comment: @martineau Good thinking - the PDF files were being generated by Docraptor, which in turn uses PrinceXML, which was throwing an htmlEntities error, causing the unexpected EOF in PyPDF for those documents.

Comment: That's good news sort of I guess. Sounds like it might be a good idea to strengthen the error handling in your script to handle bad input files as gracefully as possible.

Comment: Slightly unrelated comment - posting here because it's an early link on search engines: One gets the same error if one forgets to open the reading file stream in binary mode. So if you get the error and are a new user to PyPDF, ensure you're opening the input file with `'rb'` for "read binary".

Comment: Thanks cfi, that helped me find a paren in the wrong place!

Comment: @nerburn, have you tried this solution https://codedprojects.wordpress.com/2017/06/09/how-to-fix-pypdf-error-eof-marker-not-found/ I am in need of a solution myself but I can accomodate the errors for now, rectify later.

Answer (score 1):

You were running in an issue of PyPDF2 which was solved with [PR #321](https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/pull/321/files). The fix was released in `PyPDF2==1.27.8` (released on 2022-04-21).

Answer (score -1):

Is there is still someone looking for merging a "list" of pdfs:

Note:
Using glob to get the correct filelist. <- this will really safe your day ^^

Check this out: [glob module reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#module-glob)

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import os
import glob

class MergeAllPDF:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mergelist = []

    def create(self, filepath, outpath, outfilename):
        self.outfilname = outfilename
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.outpath = outpath
        self.pdfs = glob.glob(self.filepath)
        self.myrange = len(self.pdfs)

        for _ in range(self.myrange):
            if self.pdfs:
                self.mergelist.append(self.pdfs.pop(0))
        self.merge()

    def merge(self):
        if self.mergelist:
            self.merger = PdfFileMerger()
            for pdf in self.mergelist:
                self.merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'))  
            self.merger.write(self.outpath + "%s.pdf" % (self.outfilname))
            self.merger.close()
            self.mergelist = []
        else:
            print("mergelist is empty please check your input path")

# example how to use
#update your path here:


inpath = r"C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\mergeallpdfs\scan\*.pdf" #here are your single page pdfs stored
outpath = r"C:\Users\Fabian\Desktop\mergeallpdfs\output\\" #here your merged pdf will be stored

b = MergeAllPDF()
b.create(inpath, outpath, "mergedpdf")
```