# EOF Marker not found when using PyPDF2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, eof, pypdf

I want to create a program that merges specified PDFs in my folder into one PDF. I keep running into the "EOF Marker Not Found" when indicating multiple pdfs.

The script works without a problem with I only indicated 2 PDFs as a test run. When I try multiple, I get the EOF Marker error.

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger


#I Shortened this for the question, in reality the script was written up to
# '76.pdf'
pdfs = ['1.pdf', '2.pdf', '3.pdf', '4.pdf', '5.pdf', '6.pdf', '7.pdf', '8.pdf','9.pdf', '10.pdf']

merger = PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in pdfs:
    merger.append(pdf)

merger.write("result.pdf")
```

While there are only two elements in the list ['1.pdf', '2.pdf'] I get 'results.pdf' placed in the same file as the other pdfs (Working fine).

In this case, I get EOF marker not found at line 10:
merger.append(pdf)

Comment: For which pdf do you get the error ? Have you try to merge the first one and the one triggering the error ?

Comment: Now, when I run it, I get an error regardless of the PDFs i use.

Comment: Have you checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16162478/4744341)? Someone had a similar problem.